# why can i import module phonenumbers, when i already pip install the module

Tags: python, pip, python-import, python-packaging

```
import phonenumbers

from Number import number

from phonenumbers import geocoder
sanNumber = phoneNumber.parse(number)

yourLocation = geocoder.decription_for_number(sanNumber, "en")

print(yourLocation)
```

Comment: This needs more details... -- Often when this happens, it is because the Python interpreter used to install and the Python interpreter used to run the code are different ones: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

- `pip install phonenumber` downloads the phonenumber package from PyPI and adds it to your installation.
- Your Python installation has hundreds of packages, but for a certain project you only need a few of them.
- Within Python you 'import phonenumber', which adds it's attributes and methods to the namespace, so that you can access them with your code.
- You want to keep your namespace small to avoid ambiguities and to reduce the time Python needs to access your objects.